# Outlook 2007 - Conditional Format based on Users declining a meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, formatting, conditional-formatting

I recently set up a meeting with a colleague but must have ignored the fact that he had declined.  So I showed up to the meeting alone.

Is there any way to conditional format my Outlook 2007 calendar to change the colour / category when there are required invitees that have declined my meeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option: Under Tools|Rules and Alerts, you can create a rule to assign such responses (those that you receive containing "Declined:" to a specific category or mark it as important or set a follow up flag or move them to a special folder, etc.